# Proving that a wf is true for all finite domains.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question is from [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/mendelson.pdf) by Elliot Mendelson , exercise 2.56 , page 94.I am trying to prove that the following wf is true for all finite domains.

$$
(\forall x)(\forall y)(\forall z) [ A_1^2(x,x)\land (A_1^2(x,y)\land A_1^2(y,z) \Rightarrow A_1^2(x,z) ) \land (A_1^2(x,y) \lor A_1^2(y,x))] \Rightarrow (\exists y)(\forall x) A_1^2(y,x).
$$

My plan was to use induction with this two steps:

$(1)$ prove that it is true for a domain for $1$ element. 
$(2)$ If it is true for a domain for $n$ elements , then it is true for a domain of $(n+1)$ elements.

But I am failing at the second part.Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Is a "wf" the same thing as a wff?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In words, the formula says that "if $R$ ($\equiv A^2_1)$ is a reflexive, transitive and total relation, then there is an element that is $R$-below every element (i.e., an element $y$ such that $y \mathrel{R} x$ for every $x$)". Assume this is true for every relation $R$ on any set with $n$ elements and consider a relation $R$ that is reflexive, transitive and total on a set $X$ with $n + 1$ elements, say $X = X' \cup \{z\}$ where $z \not\in X'$ and $X'$ has $n$ elements. By assumption, there is a $y' \in X'$ such that $y' \mathrel{R} x'$ for every $x ' \in X'$. Then if $y' \mathrel{R} z$ we are done (taking $y = y'$), while if  $\lnot(y' \mathrel{R} z)$ we must have $z \mathrel{R} y'$ (by totality), implying that $z \mathrel{R} x$ for every $ x \in X$ (by transitivity and reflexivity) (so that we can take $y = z$).